# prove that , every normal subgroup of this group $G$ of the form $G_I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

let $K_1 , K_2 , .. , K_n$ are non-abelian simple groups and let $G =  K_1 \times K_2 \times .. \times  K_n$

prove that , every normal subgroup of $G$ of the for $G_I$ for some subset $I$ of {$1,2,..,n$}

to define $G_I$

let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are groups and $I$ be subset of  {$1,2,...,n$}

$G_I=${$(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) | a_k \in A_k ,  1\le k \le n  , a_i=1$ if $i\not\in I $ }

---

now , the text gives me a hint which is to suppose N is normal and $ x \in N , x=(a_1,...,a_n)$ with $ a_i \neq 1$ for some $i $ and then show that there is some $g_i \in G_i $ not commuting with $a_i$ and show that $[(1,...,g_i,...,1),x] \in K_i\cap N$ and then deduce that $K_i \le N$

now , the problem is , $g_i$ is $n$-tupe and $a_i$ is not a tuple , so how can they commute or not commute ?! this is not defined ! the same thing with the commutator .

Comment: At first sight, this looks like horribly sloppy notation. The notation $G_i$ suggests to mean $G_{\{i\}}$, but the hint suggests it should actually be $K_i$. Furthermore, the $K_i$ in $K_i\cap N$ looks like it should be $(1\times\ldots 1\times K_i\times1\times\ldots\times 1)\cap N$. And where do the groups $A_i$ come from at all? $A_i\leq K_i$?

Comment: @HSN , those $A_i$'s are just to define what is $G_I$ .  no more of that .

Comment: What text? What page?

Comment: @GerryMyerson , Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote , 3rd ed , chapter 5 ,setion 4 , problem #18 page 174, i have made most of the proof ! just a pit step to complete it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in Dummit and Foote is actually pretty iffy. In the hint, they are referencing an earlier problem in which the setup is the same except that the $K_i$ are called $G_i$. Thus, you should interpret $g_i$ as an element of $K_i$.

If you would like a further hint as to the actual solution, feel free to ask.